# CSS3 positioning below sticky menu

Tags: css

I want to make my menu stuck at the top of the page, so I use `position: fixed`, but i have a problem with the content below the menu - I cannot position it. For exsample `margin-top` doesn't work, and I can't understand why is this.
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8gjfLe5d/1/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to give the menu id a `top` and `left`

```
#menu{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

edit:
it's something to do with the content tag

https://jsfiddle.net/wgg9bkmr/2/

Comment: You're right, I was a little too quick on that one. See my update

Answer (score 0):

Give the menu a top position of `0`

```
#menu{ 
    top:0;
}

#content{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

And apply style/positioning to your content div with an id or class. I've used id's because that is what you chose, but it's considered best practice these days to use classes for all styling. Reserve the use of ID's for javascript hooks.

Here's your fix: https://jsfiddle.net/8gjfLe5d/2/

Answer (score 0):

well you have a couple of issues in your code, first as @mgiesa said you have to put

```
top:0;
```

the other issue is content is not a valid tag, as such it doesn't have the dafualt positioning and display properties automatically added by the user agent.

if you use .content as a class you should have no issues as demonstrated by this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z31vk662/)